# recursion method keeps crashing (change algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

```
//amt = amount of cents to get change for
//onhand = array of available coins . Ex: {3, 0, 1, 0} = 3 quart, 0 dime, 1 nickel, 0 pennies

//denoms = {25, 10, 5, 1}

//ndenoms = 4 ; i.e the number of different denominations

// thechange = array of change. Ex: if amt = 80, then one possible thechange = {3, 0, 1, 0} b/c 3*25 + 1*5 = 80 cents



int i = 0;

void makechange(int amt, int *onhand, int *denoms, int ndenoms, int *thechange)
   {            

      if ( (denoms[i] * onhand[i]) > amt)
         {
                    onhand[i]--;    // # of coins is too much, decrement and try again
                    makechange(amt, onhand, denoms, ndenoms, thechange); // try agan
         }

      thechange[i] = onhand[i]; //found #of coins

      amt = amt - denoms[i]*onhand[i]; // get remaining amount from change
      i++;

      if (amt != 0) // we're not done with change so move on to next denomination
      {
           makechange(amt, onhand, denoms, ndenoms, thechange);
      }   


      else if (amt == 0) // we're done with the change so all the other # coins = 0
      {
           for (int j = i; j < amt; j++)
             {
              thechange[j] = 0;
             }
      }




   }   






Now, down in main when I actually call the function prototype and print out the result

//


makechange(amt, onhand, denoms, ndenoms, thechange);

  for (int k = 0; k < ndenoms; k++)
  {
      cout << thechange[i] << " ";
  }


//
```

I get an error.

This algorithm seems seems sensible to me, does anyone know why it keeps crashing, though?

Have I properly used recursion here?

Comment: How does it crash? Do you get an error when it does? And what language is this?

Comment: I'm using C++ and compiling with devc++

Comment: Whenever, I compile and run i get "change.exe has stopped working" so I assume a seg fault or something?

Comment: Tag changed to `c++` for consistency with the language and compiler used by the OP

Answer (score 1):

If you call `makechange` twice, the second time it won't work because the global variable `i` will be wrong.

Also what should happen if you try to `makechange` and don't have enough change on hand to make it?

Similarly what happens if you have 3 quarters and 3 dimes, and are asked to make 80 cents in change?  Your algorithm will use all 3 quarters and then get stuck.

Comment: @ted-stevens: Your algorithm assumes that `i` starts off at 0.  If you've called `makechange` already, it is no longer 0, and you'll never look at your first denomination.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean

```
for (int k = 0; k < ndenoms; k++) { cout << thechange[k] << " "; }
```

a little typo made possible by the use of global variable i.

also

```
      for (int j = i; j < amt; j++) { thechange[j] = 0; }
```

I think you meant

```
for (int j = i; j < ndenoms; j++)
```

depending on the final value of amt, this will cause you to run off the end of the array, resulting in a crash.

you can solve this more easily without recursion.  are you required to use recursion for an assignment?  if not, try this:
`int makechange(int amt, int *onhand, int *denoms, int ndenoms, int *thechange)
{

    for (int i=0; i < ndenoms && amt > 0; i++)
    {
        while (onhand[i] > 0 && denoms[i] <= amt)
        {
            onhand[i]--; // use one coin
            thechange[i]++;
            amt -= denoms[i];
        }
    }
    return amt; // this is the amount you owe if you dont have enough on hand
}`

Comment: ^ thanks, but even after that it still crashes. Can anyone copy and paste my code and try it please?

Comment: Try adding print statements at entry and exit of makechange.  You might realize what is wrong when you can see the context of the crash.

Comment: also you are not checking for i>= ndenoms as an exit condition.  You can get subscript out of range after the last i++ if you are not careful.

Comment: ^ How come the algorithm loops forever?

Comment: I don't need an exit statement, do I? The function will not call itself anymore once (amt == 0) and complete the rest of main. So isn't this enough?

Comment: i edited my answer.  look at your loop to zero the remaining coins.  you are looping up to amt instead of ndenoms.

Comment: This algorithm still doesn't work for @btilly's 3x25,3x10 case.

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes as mentioned by shsmith and here is the modified and complete c++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
```

`using namespace std;`

`int i = 0;`

```
void makechange(int amt, int *onhand, int *denoms, int ndenoms, int *thechange)
{
    if ( (denoms[i] * onhand[i]) > amt)
    {
            onhand[i]--;    // # of coins is too much, decrement and try again
            makechange(amt, onhand, denoms, ndenoms, thechange); // try agan
    }

    thechange[i] = onhand[i]; //found #of coins
    amt = amt - denoms[i]*onhand[i]; // get remaining amount from change
    i++;
    if (amt != 0) // we're not done with change so move on to next denomination
    {
            makechange(amt, onhand, denoms, ndenoms, thechange);
    }
    else if (amt == 0) // we're done with the change so all the other # coins = 0
    {
            for (int j = i; j < ndenoms; j++)
            {
                    thechange[j] = 0;
            }
    }}
```

`int main(){`

```
    //Now, down in main when I actually call the function prototype and print out the result
    int amt = 80, onhand[] = {3, 0, 1, 0}, denoms[] = {25, 10, 5, 1}, ndenoms = 4, thechange[4];
    makechange(amt, onhand, denoms, ndenoms, thechange);
    for (int k = 0; k < ndenoms; k++)
    {
            cout << thechange[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;}
```

This code is running perfectly on my machine. I compiled it using Cygwin.

Note: This algorithm would work only if you have the denomination coins more or correctly onhand. If there are insufficient number of coins onhand, then there is no exit for the recursive method because 'amt' would never become zero. At the same time, you never check for the 'i' value whether it is in bounds of the 'ndenoms'. This could also result in out of boundary errors which could cause ur program to exit incorrectly.